# Child combinator vs Cascading: Which is better performant and efficient?

Tags: javascript, css

**Child combinator:**

```
#main-navigation-wrapper > .main-navigation > .top-nav > .top-menu > .in {
    /* some styling */
}
```

The same thing can be represented in a less specific way like so (**Cascading**, or is it called something else??):

```
#main-navigation-wrapper .main-navigation .in {
    /* some styling */
}
```

Theoretically which one of the two would be better performant and efficient as per the given example? (Please don't say it's negligible.)

### My Use Case

Since the community members have always advised me to describe what I am trying to achieve in my question, here goes.

I use [Twitter Bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) for some JavaScript effects, and here's the snippet I use:

```
!function ($) {

  "use strict"; // jshint ;_;


 /* COLLAPSE PUBLIC CLASS DEFINITION
  * ================================ */

  var Collapse = function (element, options) {
     this.$element = $(element)
     this.options = $.extend({}, $.fn.collapse.defaults, options)

     if (this.options.parent) {
       this.$parent = $(this.options.parent)
     }

     this.options.toggle && this.toggle()
  }

  Collapse.prototype = {

     constructor: Collapse

  , dimension: function () {
       var hasWidth = this.$element.hasClass('width')
       return hasWidth ? 'width' : 'height'
     }

  , show: function () {
       var dimension
         , scroll
         , actives
         , hasData

       if (this.transitioning) return

       dimension = this.dimension()
       scroll = $.camelCase(['scroll', dimension].join('-'))
       actives = this.$parent && this.$parent.find('> .main-navigation > .top-nav > .top-menu > .in')

       if (actives && actives.length) {
         hasData = actives.data('collapse')
         if (hasData && hasData.transitioning) return
         actives.collapse('hide')
         hasData || actives.data('collapse', null)
       }

  /* and the code goes on... */

}(window.jQuery);
```

Look for this in the code -- `> .main-navigation > .top-nav > .top-menu > .in`.

Now, should I be using that, or this `> .main-navigation .in`? That's my question, and reasoning should be based on which one'd offer better performance, and which one's more efficient.

Please let me know if I am not clear enough.

### My guess?

I think this (`#main-navigation-wrapper > .main-navigation > .top-nav > .top-menu > .in`) is both more efficient and performant as I believe it helps the browser identify the element quickly. I could be wrong though, and that's why I am asking.

Comment: are worried about jquery perfs? or css perfs? not the same thing.

Comment: @mpm can I get info on both? Then I'll be in a position to choose which way to go. :)

Comment: That is not cascading. You're simply swapping the child combinator out for the descendant combinator, and losing a few intermediate classes.

Comment: for javascript benchmarking try jsperf. And yes your css issue is totally negligible , especially when using bloated frameworks like bootstrap that declare a ton of rules you'll never use. Further more , what is costly is the repaint operation , ie the rules themselves when applied dynamically, how many dom elements are affected by the rules , what area of the page, etc ... that css "lookup" issue should be the least of your worries.

Answer (score 0):

All the comments are correct, the effect is negligible.

Also, it is important that the 2 rules are not the same. In some cases, they can give very different results. So, choosing one or the other is not a matter of perfomance, is a matter of getting what you really want.

Having said all this, you are right, the child rule is more efficient **if it is correct.**

If you are writing the rule, and you know your DOM, and the rule is not overspecific, it is more efficient. writing overspecific rules is a problem that you can avoid because you know your DOM, but a framework writer cannot avoid.

What really makes the difference is when you have a lot of content inside

```
#main-navegation-wrapper not(.main-navigation)
```

that the first rule doesn't even process, and the second has to